# PgAdmin: backup and restore schemas using the GUI

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore, schema, pgadmin

I know how to backup and restore one or more schema(s) from a PostgreSQL database using psql:

1. Go to the folder that contains the executables of PostgreSQL:

cd C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin

2. Connect to the database:

psql -U user -p port -d database

2. Rename the schema to lowercases:

ALTER SCHEMA "schema_name"

RENAME TO "lowercase_schema_name";

3. Exit PostgreSQL:

\q

3. Save the schema(s) using the -n flag:

pg_dump -U user -p port -n schema1 -n schema2 database > "C:\path\to\directory\schema_backup.sql"

4. Add the schema(s) to the desired database (the existing schemas are preserved):

psql -U user -p port -d database -f"C:\path\to\directory\schema_backup.sql"

This procedure works well and is quick to perform. However, as I have to ask uninitiated people to do it, I would have liked not to have to go through the command prompt, but **only through PgAdmin GUI**.

It is very simple in PgAdmin to export and import an entire database by right-clicking on the database and using the backup and restore tools. However, I can't do the same thing just for one particular schema. In the same way as with psql (as described above), I want to save only one (ore more) schema(s) and then import it into a given database. When I save the schema in .sql format, create a new blank schema (for example in the same database) and restore the saved schema, **the tables of the new schema are empty**...

Any idea how to do this? Maybe I have to change some parameters in Dump options?

[image]